# Starting to trouble shoot electric furnace failure, I need some suggestions where to start

Tags: electrical, furnace

A little more info prior to failure. The main service line pulled loose from the top of the sevice pole to the residence, which caused major issues to appliances and outlets throughout the home.
Once service line was repaired I was able to run the A/C no issues, but when I switch to heat it does not function. The breakers for furnace did trip out with the failure,
The Furnace is a E4EB-017H Nortek.

Comment: I don't understand.  If the furnace breakers trip, how do you expect it to work? What happens when you reset the breakers?  Does the electric oven and dryer make heat properly?  Could you maybe [edit] to clarify and help narrow down what to look at...

Comment: There's a reasonable chance that electrical things were fried inside the furnace itself. I'm all for DIY, but if it's getting cold, you'll want heat quickly, and it seems you're starting from ground zero in terms of DIY HVAC knowledge. Unfortunately, the fastest and most cost effective method of finding out what's gone wrong might just be to call in a pro.

Comment: Generally when the power company's service connection failure fries your household electrics, it's on the power company to make that right. If the HV line came into contact with the 240V service line on its way down, your stuff may have experienced 10-50 times the voltage it's designed to handle (depending on local distribution voltage), which tends to fry things permanently.

Answer (score 2):

Start with verifying you have 240 Volt phase to phase at the furnace.

Disconnect the power and verify the heating elements are not shorted out using an Ohm meter, it should not be infinite (broken) and higher than zero ohms

Check the thermostat is delivering 24 volts when in heat mode to the relay on the furnace.

Comment: 240 Volt phase to phase *at the furnace*, +1. I just did an electric furnace where I failed to diagnose it correctly. Fuses were good. Bypassed the t-stat. There was 120 to ground and 240 across all three phases *at the disconnect*. The problem was one of the blades of the disconnect wasn't connecting right.